Why does my console keep bringing up a 'method (405) not allowed' in my deployed app?
I recently developed a weather prediction app that uses OpenAI's gpt-3.5-turbo.
When I run it in my local environment, it works perfectly, but when I deploy to either Vercel, Netlify, or Cloudflare, it does not work. It prints a method (405) not allowed in the console.
This is my HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weather Predictor</title>
    <style> 
    body {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh; /* Set the height of the body to 100% of the viewport height */
            margin-top: 150px; 
            margin-bottom: 150px;
            padding: 0; /* Remove default padding */
            flex-direction: column; /* Stack elements vertically */
            text-align: center; /* Center text horizontally */
            background-image: url('https://imgur.com/a/Z3uSG4q');
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            background-size: cover; /* Cover the entire viewport */
            background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
        }

        form {
            width: 400px; /* Set the width of the form */
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); /* Add a semi-transparent white background to the form */
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px; /* Add rounded corners */
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Add a shadow effect */
        }

        input[type="submit"] {
            background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green background color */
            color: white; /* White text color */
            padding: 5px 10px; /* Padding for the button */
            font-size: 16px; /* Font size of the text */
            border: none; /* Remove the border */
            border-radius: 5px; /* Add rounded corners */
            cursor: pointer; /* Change cursor to pointer on hover */
        }

        /* Change styles on hover */
        input[type="submit"]:hover {
            background-color: #45a049; /* Darker green on hover */
        }

        /* Add any other CSS styles here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Weather Predictor</h1>
    <form id="predictionForm" method="post" action="/">
        <label for="date">Date</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Predict Match">
    </form><br>
    <div id="predictionResult"></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("predictionForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission

            var date = document.getElementById("date").value;

            var jsonData = {
                "date": date,
            };

            fetch('/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                displayPrediction(data.prediction);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });

        function displayPrediction(prediction) {
            var predictionResultElement = document.getElementById("predictionResult");
            predictionResultElement.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous content
            var predictionText = document.createTextNode("Prediction: " + prediction);
            predictionResultElement.appendChild(predictionText);
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>

This is my Python:
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json
from openai import OpenAI

# Initialize OpenAI client
client = OpenAI()

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/favicon.ico':
            self.send_response(404)
            self.end_headers()
            return

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
            html_content = file.read()

        self.wfile.write(html_content.encode('utf-8'))

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)

        try:
            data = json.loads(post_data.decode('utf-8'))
            print("Received data:", data)

            date = data.get('date', '')

            if not date:
                prediction = "Please enter date."
            else:
                response = client.chat.completions.create(
                    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
                    messages=[
                        {
                            "role": "system",
                            "content": "You will be provided with a date. You are to predict the weather in Lagos, Nigeria for that date. You should tell the maximum and minimum temperatures for that day and if it will rain or not. Don't talk too much, just be straight to the point and say the predicted weather"
                        },
                        {
                            "role": "user",
                            "content": f"{date}"
                        }
                    ],
                    temperature=0.1,
                    max_tokens=100,
                    top_p=1
                )
                prediction = response.choices[0].message.content

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)
            prediction = "Error occurred while generating prediction."

        # Ensure prediction is serializable
        if not isinstance(prediction, str):
            prediction = str(prediction)

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

        response_data = json.dumps({"prediction": prediction})
        self.wfile.write(response_data.encode('utf-8'))

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=RequestHandler, port=8080):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print('Starting server...')
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    print('Stopping server...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()


could it be CORS ?

no its not CORS
